# associate a column of another array on pdfmake

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, pdfmake

In my project I want to associate the values of an array other than the one present in the first two columns. It's possible? (The number of value of `partialPrice` is identical to the number of `code` present). I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
interv: Intervention[]
partialPrice = []
{
          table: {
            headerRows: 1,
            widths: ['auto', 'auto', 'auto'],
            body: [
              ['Code', 'Description', 'Price'],
              ...this.interv.map(intervObj => 
                  [intervObj.intervention.code, intervObj.intervention.description],
                  this.partialPrice.map(price =>
                    [price])
              )
            ]
          }
        },
```

Comment: please add an element to the partialPrice array.

Comment: @sofa_maniac `partialPrice` have only number, for example, `[12.23, 428.17, 32.9, 35]`

Comment: how exactly do you want this array to appear in that table? which element and on what basis?

Comment: @sofa_maniac These array elements must appear one below the other on the third column of the table

Comment: so, first row gets 12.23, second row gets 428.17... like that?

Comment: @sofa_maniac exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need to extract the element from the `partialPrice` array depending on the current index of the `map()` that you are using on the `interv` array. So, this should work:

```
  body: [
          ['Code', 'Description', 'Price'],
          ...this.interv.map((intervObj, index) => 
              [intervObj.intervention.code, intervObj.intervention.description, partialPrice[index]]
          )
        ]
```